# Is it possible to have 2 gradient backgrounds?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, gradient

I am trying to have a div 500px by 200px have 2 linear gradient backgrounds. I already tried

```
style="background-color: #000000; 
       background-image: linear-gradient(400deg, #000000 0%, #ffffff 74%), linear-
       gradient(350deg, #000000 74%, #ffffff 0%);
       background-size: 100px 80px;
       background-position: bottom right, top left;
       background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;"
```

but that only gave me the last background-image. (I did the above without line breaks though, I included line breaks to make reading my code easier)

**Is it possible to have 2 linear gradient backgrounds in one div?**

Comment: you need to define a size and position for each one

Comment: Personally I would use 2 div's with differend ID's and use z-index and positions absolute and relative.

Comment: It's quite possible to have two, or more, linear-gradients making up a background-image as you have. Your CSS is creating a black and white jagged effect - what were you aiming for?

Comment: I am aiming to have a black and white jagged effect on one half of the div and a linear gradient black to white or (vice verca) on the other half